# Mobile connect api to update opt in/opt out status

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Can anyone post the complete rest request to update mobile connect opt in/opt out status in sfmc through api.

Comment: Did you ever found a way on how to achieve this? I am trying to do this but I am not even sure where to start

Answer (score 1):

1. Request Token:

```
curl --location --request POST '<< your endpoint API>> /v1/requestToken' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--form 'clientId=XXXXXX' \
--form 'clientSecret=XXXXX'
```

2. Opt-in, suscribe to a keyword:

```
curl --location --request POST '<< your endpoint API>>/sms/v1/queueMO' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer << the token you received >>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "mobileNumbers": [
    "XXXXXXXXXX"
  ],
  "shortCode": "<< the keyword short code",
  "messageText": "<< the keyword>> "
}'
```

[image]

3. opt-out, you need to subscribe to a STOP keyword

```
{
  "mobileNumbers": [
    "XXXXXX"
  ],
  "shortCode": "XXXXXXX",
  "messageText": "STOP"
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You are best reading the official API documentation below and posting a specific question where you are having issues.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm

Comment: Wouldnt this be better off as a comment as opposed to an answer?